# How can I execute TEST SUITES in robotframework in a specific order?

Tags: testing, jenkins, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I have my tests set up in the following structure using Robotframework:

```
Directory1: 
  - SuiteA
  - SuiteB
  - SuiteC

Directory2: 
  - SuiteA
  - SuiteB
```

I want to execute all of the test suites from Directory1 first before executing the suites in Directory2 using "[pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot)". The test suites from Directory2 are dependent on test suites from Directory1 so the execution must be in this order. How can I order the execution this way?

I was reading online about using an argument file to specify the order of execution but I was not able to figure that out. I also read the documentation from Robotframework and named my test suites accordingly with the "number__testsuitename" naming convention but that did not work either.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A higher level Test Suite Directory should work... MainSuite (Directory1, Directory2)

Comment: In general,test suites should be independent as you may see from your example,it creates a mess when there are dependencies between. Another note is, you would like to run testcases parallel but also with specified order due to dependencies - for me it is contradictory. Regarding execution: it is depth-wise with alphabetic ordering, --randomise will shuffle tests order. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-execution

Comment: I know it's pretty bad to have dependent test suites , but unfortunately I have no control over how these test cases are written. Anyways , I was able to run these test suites in order with pybot using an argument file, but I am having trouble with running them in parallel and in order with "pabot"

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to modify the `.pabotsuitenames` file with the tests/suites that you want to run in parallel and also add the `#WAIT` flag in case that you need to run something sequentially, for example:

```
datasources:7a60d412cbd2efd728502cddce7ce4cd4b57aa42
commandlineoptions:65f95c924ba97541f47949701c4e3c51192a5b43
suitesfrom:no-suites-from-option
file:984cbf6a94ce4d05453079d2eedf2399a3cae664
--suite Directory 1 Name.Suite A Name 
--suite Directory 1 Name.Suite B Name
--suite Directory 1 Name.Suite C Name
#WAIT
--suite Directory 2 Name.Suite A Name 
--suite Directory 2 Name.Suite B Name
```

`pabot` does provide options to control the level of parallelism and the order of execution. It is described in readme file of the project:

> *.pabotsuitenames file contains the list of suites that will be executed. File is created during pabot execution if not already there. The file is a cache that pabot uses when re-executing same tests to speed up processing. This file can be partially manually edited. First 4 rows contain information that should not be edited - pabot will edit these when something changes. After this come the suite names.*
>
> *There are three possibilities to influence the execution:*
>
> *The order of suites can be changed.
> If a directory (or a directory structure) should be executed sequentially, add the directory suite name to a row.
> You can add a line with text #WAIT to force executor to wait until all previous suites have been executed.*

[Pabot Github](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot#controlling-execution-order-and-level-of-parallelism)

Answer (score 0):

pabot is not working very well with a suite structure e.g. "01__B_Test" because it will be turned into “B_Test”. This means that suites will be executed in alphabetical order and not in numbering order. To fix this, all suites would have to be included in .pabotsuitenames to adjust the order again. With hundreds of suites, this is more than cumbersome.